# Unable to write data to GCP-MySQL

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
 1. LOCAL : CSV FILE-> PYSAPRK-> MYSQL

 2. DATAPROC CLUSTER: Google bucket -> Pyspark -> Google Cloud Platform MySQL.
```

Locally I'm able to read csv file and write data into local MYSQL database.

When I run same code in dataproc cluster - I'm able fetch the google bucket data,but not able to write data into Mysql database;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Like John said, we need code...it could be one of many different things preventing you from writing to the database. :)